# Line breaking code in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This line seems to break my code in IE8, can anyone tell me why

```
data=[];
item=someElementWithTextInside
//line below breaks it
data.push({obj: item, text: item.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, ""))}; 
//line above breaks
```

I've already tried looking at the innerHTML part of it, that function seems to work fine on my browser (and switching to innerText doesn't effect anything)

Comment: By saying "in IE8", I assume that means it works in other browsers, right?

Comment: ...if the issue is really the mismatched brackets/parentheses, then you need to start testing your code using the developer tools built into most browsers. This is basic debugging that should happen long before you ask a question here.

Comment: Hey jack, are you there? At this point I'd guess that this is just another *"I'm too lazy to perform the basic tasks expected of a real programmer"* question.

Comment: @amnotiam +1 to that. I mean, if jack had bothered testing in anything but IE8 he'd have noticed that it didn't work there either...

Answer (score 3):

You should have `)});` at the end of the line, not `))};`.